# Boundedness of travelling front norm

Tags: partial-differential-equations

For a reaction diffusion equation $u_t=u_{xx}+f(u)$, assume that $\mu_1<\mu_2$ are equilibria and
$V(\xi), \xi=x-ct$ with $c>0$  is a traveling front, where $\lim_{\xi\to -\infty}V(\xi)=\mu_2$ and $\lim_{\xi\to\infty}V(\xi)=\mu_1$.

In particular, $\partial_x V(\xi)=V'(\xi)<0$.

Is it possible to say that 
$$
\lVert V'(\xi-q)\rVert=\sqrt{\langle V'(\xi-q),V'(\xi-q)}=\left(\int_\mathbb{R}e^{c\xi}V'(\xi-q)^2\, d\xi\right)^{1/2}
$$

and, similarly, $\lVert V''(\xi-q)\rVert$,
are bounded?

(here $q$ is just a fixed real which describes a translation of the front)

The inner product is defined by
$$
\langle f,g\rangle=\int_\mathbb{R}e^{c\xi}fg\, d\xi
$$
with corresponding norm
$$
\lVert x\rVert=\sqrt{\langle x,x\rangle}.
$$

*Isn't this simply true since each norm is a non-negative real number?*

Comment: Please clear up the formatting. Why does the left hand side depend on $\xi$and the righat hand side doesn't? Please define the scalar product clearly.

Comment: I do not get your point. Both the LHS and the RHS depend on $\xi$.

Comment: Substitute $\zeta  \leftarrow \xi$ in the RHS, then it does not depend on $\xi$.

Answer (score 1):

In the case where $\mu_1 = 0, \, \mu_2 = 1, f'(0) = 1$ and $f$ is concave down, the travelling front has the asymptotic behavior $V(\xi) \sim e^{-r\xi}$ with $r = \frac{c - \sqrt{c^2-4}}{2}$. This follows from a linearization argument.

Since $f(V)$ has the same asymptotic behavior as $V$ at $+\infty$, it follows that $V'$ and $V''$ have the same asymptotic behavior at $+ \infty$.

Therefore $\xi \mapsto e^{c\xi} (V')^2(\xi)$ and $\xi \mapsto e^{c\xi} (V'')^2(\xi)$ are not integrable at $+ \infty$.